# Is assignable to type but could not be instantiated with a different subtype

Tags: typescript

I have some typescript code:

```
const wrapField = <T extends { value: string }>(fieldValue: string): T => ({
  value: fieldValue,
});
```

Typescript gives me an error:

```
'{ value: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ value: string; }'
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, they are both `'{value: string;}'`

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan Cavanaugh from the TypeScript team explained, a function like `fn<T extends SomeType>(): T` [cannot possibly be implemented correctly](https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/1205170798282960896). He goes on to say:

> People want to write
>
> `const x = fn<SomeType>();`
>
> when they mean
>
> `const x = fn() as SomeType;`
>
> because type assertions feel bad

Generics are used when there's a relationship with two or more types. In your function, there is no such relationship — the return type is always the same and doesn't depend on anything. You can write it without generics.

```
const wrapField = (fieldValue: string): { value: string } => ({
  value: fieldValue,
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: As @Karol Majewski stated, a generic function is probably something you don't need in this specific case. However, my answer below has to do with the error as is, i.e. solving the problem while keeping keeping the function generic, in case someone else gets the same error or if this is just a simplified version of the problem .

---

You'll have to cast it, i.e. do:

```js
const wrapField = <T extends { value: string }>(fieldValue: string): T => ({
  value: fieldValue,
} as T);
```

The issue is that `T` can have more properties that are potentially required than just `value` (the `extends` part just says that `value` is one of those properties and that it must be a string), and because the return type of your function is `T`, TypeScript does not want to assume that `{ value: fieldValue }` will always be `T` unless you tell it to by casting the object.