# Is assignable but could be instantiated with a different subtype

Tags: typescript, generics, enums, config, extends

I want to create a generic function to work with the type of only passed argument and not any type from enum.

There is a simplified example.

```
enum EAnimals {
  dog = 'dog',
  cat = 'cat',
}

interface IConfig<T extends EAnimals> {
  animalType: T
}

const configs: {[animalType in EAnimals]: IConfig<animalType>} = {
  [EAnimals.cat]: {
    animalType: EAnimals.cat
  },
  [EAnimals.dog]: {
    animalType: EAnimals.dog
  }
}

function doSomething<T extends EAnimals> (animalTypeParam: T): IConfig<T> {
  return configs[animalTypeParam]; // error
}
```

I've seen [60730845](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60730845/is-assignable-to-type-but-could-not-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype) but I want to use generics. For example, here it's impossible to create config for `EAnimals.cat` where `animalType` is anything besides `EAnimals.cat`. If I do `doSomething(EAnimals.cat)` I will know that returned config is for `cat`. If I declare parameter's type as `animalTypeParam: EAnimals` I will have to also declare returned type as `IConfig<EAnimals>` which ruins the idea.

I understand that it happens because `T extends ...` can be bigger than original enum but I couldn't find something like `in` for generics.

The main purpose of this is to get rid of human factor when creating configs and functions to work with this configs. If there's another working solution, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just overload it:

```js
enum EAnimals {
    dog = 'dog',
    cat = 'cat',
}

interface IConfig<T extends EAnimals> {
    animalType: T
}

const configs: { [animalType in EAnimals]: IConfig<animalType> } = {
    [EAnimals.cat]: {
        animalType: EAnimals.cat
    },
    [EAnimals.dog]: {
        animalType: EAnimals.dog
    }
}

function doSomething<T extends EAnimals>(animalTypeParam: T):IConfig<T>
function doSomething<T extends EAnimals>(animalTypeParam: T) {
    return configs[animalTypeParam]; // ok
}

const result = doSomething(EAnimals.cat) // IConfig<EAnimals.cat>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAoggiAlhAhgGwM5QN4CgoFQAmA9gOZQC8UA5KWTQDT6EDGKALlbex07gF9cuRCA7AATgDMUrYFACSAYRIgpiMgB4AKlGAAPcSCJZ4SVJgB8OFgRTn02gJ4AHYAC4o2wcNaqMXH5qGhie2FAA2vbIjq7yorAIMZgAup7Kqupa0RbObtYC3HiEkWbJGAB0vGk2JSU5sW6eZRaVvLZQAswlES3olfQ1xXV2Dmh5HoljA%20QdQkK4UmAgrByIqsQkAMokEMAcABaiWroGRiZT5ZYAFA3jcQAKKBIoEJ7aAJTuGcEnlovLVbrECbHZ7Q7HHR6QygC59Ky3MYTJ4vN5eD61QgSfZgCQgoJZDBRJGPZ6vFIAbigAHpqXoJBISBIfEA)

**UPDATE**

There are two alternative ways to handle it.

**First - make partial application**

```js
enum EAnimals {
    dog = 'dog',
    cat = 'cat',
}

interface IConfig<T extends EAnimals> {
    animalType: T
}

const configs = {
    [EAnimals.cat]: {
        animalType: EAnimals.cat
    },
    [EAnimals.dog]: {
        animalType: EAnimals.dog
    }
} as const

type Config = { [animalType in EAnimals]: IConfig<animalType> }

const doSomething = <C extends Config>(config: C) => <T extends EAnimals>(animalTypeParam: T) => {
    return config[animalTypeParam]; 
}

const result = doSomething(configs)(EAnimals.cat)
```

But, then you need to make `configs` an immutable object.

**Second - don create config variable at all**

```js
enum EAnimals {
    dog = 'dog',
    cat = 'cat',
}

interface IConfig<T extends EAnimals> {
    animalType: T
}


type Config = { [animalType in EAnimals]: IConfig<animalType> }

const doSomething = <C extends Config>(config: C) => <T extends EAnimals>(animalTypeParam: T) => {
    return config[animalTypeParam];
}

const result = doSomething({
    [EAnimals.cat]: {
        animalType: EAnimals.cat
    },
    [EAnimals.dog]: {
        animalType: EAnimals.dog
    }
})(EAnimals.cat)
```

Comment: We also can delete the second generic type. Anyway that's good, never though of it. Can't use anything besides enum and returned type is generic, but still a hack :) Thanks!

Comment: I added another two alternative ways

Comment: Looks interesting. Will definitely try it out. Great thanks for your time, before your comment it was an extra pain for my head